Jenkins pipeline, Zip and push a file to a nexus repository
I'm working on a Jenkins pipeline whose goal is to zip a a file src/main/resources/spots/spots-1.txt and push to the nexus repository
Here is the step I'm using to zip and push the zip file
stage('Zip and push files'){
            
                script {                  
                    sh '''
                        cd src/main/resources/spots
                        zip spots-$VERSION.zip spots-1.txt
                        ls -al
                        zipinfo spots-$VERSION.zip
                    '''
                }
                nexusArtifactUploader(
                    nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
                    protocol: 'https',
                    nexusUrl: 'myNexusUrl',
                    groupId: 'QA',
                    version: "$VERSION",
                    credentialsId: "nexus3",
                    repository: 'maven-releases',
                    artifacts: [
                        [artifactId: 'spots-artifact',
                         classifier: '',
                         file: 'src/main/resources/spots/spots-$VERSION.zip',
                         type: 'zip']
                    ]
                 )
    }

But after pushing to the nexus, the folder included in the zip is empty. The zip does not contain the expected file.
Is there anything missing in my script please?
Thanks a lot.

What's the output of zipinfo?

Hi @Iterokun after restarting Jenkins, the issue got solved. The code is working fine. Thanks. Please do you know if it is possible to achieve the same goal without nexusArtifactUploader? I would like to avoid installing new plugin. Thanks a lot

This is not an interactive QnA, close this question and open a new one.
